# SQL Server CASE expression that does not result in waterfall

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a case expression is there a way it does not work as a waterfall?

For example if I have the following dataset:

```
group    value
---------------
derek    5
cait     1
david    2
denver   3
```

Is there a way I  can show the following results

```
CASE 
    WHEN group like 'd%' then d
    WHEN group like 'de% then de
    ELSE other
```

To show

```
group  value
--------------
d      10
de     8
other  3
```

Right now it shows as

```
group  value
--------------
d      10
other  2
```

Comment: What does "as a Waterfall" mean? You just need to flip your `when` parts around and have the most specific first.

Comment: @DaleK - No they want to double sum when it meets both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `left join` instead:

```
select coalesce(which, 'other'), sum(t.value)
from t left join
     (values ('d%', 'd'), ('de%', 'de')
     ) v(pattern, which)
     on t.group like v.pattern
group by which;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use UNION.

```
SELECT 'd' [group], SUM(Value)[Value] FROM <table_name> WHERE [GROUP] LIKE 'd%'
UNION
SELECT 'de' [group], SUM(Value)[Value] FROM <table_name> WHERE [GROUP] LIKE 'de%'
UNION
SELECT 'other' [group], SUM(Value)[Value] FROM <table_name> WHERE [GROUP] NOT LIKE 'd%' OR [GROUP] NOT LIKE 'de%'
```